# FilterMultiValue list query does not seem to work

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow-history, filtermulivalue

I'm trying to filter the history list for a workflow (so it's an out-of-box list, not a custom one) on Office365 SharePoint 2013.  I want to be able to create a filter URL on one column with multiple values, and I've seen numerous articles saying you accomplish this with a query string format of:

`?FilterName=<internal column name>&FilterMultiValue=<value1>;<value2>`

The column I'm trying to filter on is Primary Item ID (internal column name is 'Item'), which is of type Integer, so the query string is:

`https://<server>/sites/<parent site>/<child site>/Lists/Review%20History/AllItems.aspx?FilterName=Item&FilterMultiValue=348;349;350`

However, when I try this, it results in an error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904

Is there some configuration setting change which must be made to this default SharePoint list to allow this filtered query to work?  I should add that other forms of query strings do work, such as `?FilterField1=Item&FilterValue1=348`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar case here except instead of the error message you got my view simply ignores the FilterName=x&FilterMultiValue=y;z - it all works fine with FilterField1...FilterValue1 - did you ever figure this out?